# Custom Class Loader Not Loading Class

Tags: java, classloader

```
public void launch(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final URLClassLoader ucl = (URLClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader();
    classLoader = new CustomClassLoader(ucl.getURLs());
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
    
    Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName("Main", false, classLoader);
    System.out.println(mainClass.getClassLoader().getClass().getName()); //Debug
    Method mainMethod = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] {String[].class});
    mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) args);
}
```

When This Code Is Started the Debug Line Prints "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader"
How would I fix this?

Comment: If it is printing `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, then that suggests your class is already on the class-path/module-path (e.g., you included it in a `-cp` argument, it was the main class, etc.). Class loaders, by default, delegate to their parent first, before trying to load the class themselves.

Comment: which class is the `launch` method in? Maybe `Main`?

Comment: launch is in the Loader class which calls Main

Comment: "Loader" loads class "Main" which is in a .jar file so its added with "-cp"

Comment: Then I would guess that's the problem. The entire JAR file is already visible to `Launcher$AppClassLoader`, and so that's the loader that will be used to load the classes in that JAR file. You don't appear to be setting a parent of your custom class loader, and that likely means it's [being set to the system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#%3Cinit%3E()). The output you're seeing is the system class loader.

Comment: What if you try to set the parent to `null`, if you're not already doing so?